# i want to create a star rating in JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a star rating in JavaScript in which default is 5 i will go down to 1 but i didn't understand how to fill up from 1 to 5.

Here is my code :-

```
$(".star").click(function(){
    var starselect = $(this).attr("id");
    for( var j = 5 ; j>starselect ; j--)
    {
      $("#"+j).removeClass("starchecked");
    }
    if( j < starselect+1 ){
       $("#"+j).addClass("starchecked");
    }
    $(".review-star").attr("data-rating",starselect);
});
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? Look at [jQuery rating plugins](https://www.learningjquery.com/2016/09/15-jquery-rating-plugins)

Comment: Please add html.

Comment: You don't need js for this: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh.  If you want to use js, then I would use `nextAll()`, `prevAll()` and `andSelf()` to add / remove classes

Comment: @Pete reversing the rating is not a good idea. You are basically visually upvoting, while factually downvoting and vice versa. For such a solution you also need to reverse the fields, which is very counter-intuitive.

Comment: @GevorgHakobyan obviously that's just an example of how to do it with css (that I didn't write) and you can just reverse the order of the stars if you want it the other way around - it's not exactly rocket science is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, I would do this using css, but if you need to use js, then I would use a mixture of [`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/), [`prevAll`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and [`andSelf`](https://api.jquery.com/andself/) - see comments in code

```js
var $stars = $(".star")

$stars.click(function() {
  var $star = $(this);
  if ($star.hasClass('checked')) {
    // if current clicked star is checked
    if ($star.next().hasClass('checked')) {
      // check if next star is also checked
      $star.nextAll().removeClass('checked');            // if next is then disable all following
    } else {
      $star.nextAll().andSelf().removeClass('checked');  // if not then disable self and all after (shouldn't need all after, but just in case)
    }
    $star.prevAll().addClass('checked'); // check all before

    // if you just want to remove all stars on click of an already checked box, remove the above 2 lines and just ue the below:
    // $stars.removeClass('checked');
  } else {
    $star.nextAll().removeClass('checked'); // remove checked from all following the clicked
    $star.prevAll().andSelf().addClass('checked'); // add checked to this and all previous
  }

  var starselect = $stars.index($star) + 1; // get current star rating
  $(".review-star").attr("data-rating", starselect);
  console.log(starselect);
});
```

```css
.star {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="star">1</span>
<span class="star">2</span>
<span class="star">3</span>
<span class="star">4</span>
<span class="star">5</span>
```